# REST API design for utility calculations

Tags: rest

I'm trying to design an API that balances RESTful recommended practices with overall usability  and one thing that I'm struggling with is the design of utility methods for calculating things.

Specifically, for homebrewing there are many things the brewer wants to calculate during the process: color, bitterness, ABV, etc.  I guess it's simple enough to have a `/calculators` endpoint with the resulting `GET` returning available calculators:

- /calculators/1
- /calculators/2

though in this case it's certainly more user-friendly to return:

- /calculators/abv
- /calculators/ibu

What should the `GET` on a calculator resource look like?  Should the values that make up the calculation be URL params (`/calculators/abv?og=1.050&fg=1.021`)?  What's the appropriate response/response code when the necessary params aren't provided or an invalid combination of params is provided?  Is there a more sensible design other than the resource per calculation type that I specify above?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few response codes you could use, 400 is general 'client error', so it would be one of those. You can include a body too to explain what is wrong.

The way you have formed the get request seems reasonable enough to me, it's hard to say as it's a bit of a contrived example.

For simple calculations, that format might work ok. For more complex calculations, you might want to consider having a single argument that encodes the entire calculation, think `6 * 9 ^ 10 / 6`.